# Filter entities by a condition within a collection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The simplified question would be:

Having in a “A” entity, a collection of “B” entities (from a OneToMany relationship) and using CriteriaBuilder, how to get the elements from "A" that have in this collection at least one element "B" that meets a condition? (for example B has a property equal to 10, or as another example B points to another entity whose property is equal to 10).

To put in context:

In my program I have the following entities

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "S_EXPEDIENT")
public class Expedient {
  private Long idExpedient
  private Integer numberExpedient
  private Integer yearExpedient
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_chamber")
  private Chamber chamber
  private Integer status
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "expedient")
  private List<HistoricalAssignment> assignments = new ArrayList<HistoricalAssignment>();
  //more fields
}

@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "S_HISTORICAL_ASSIGNMENT ")
@Entity
public class HistoricalAssignment {
  private Long idHistoricalAssignment
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_expedient")
  private Expedient expedient;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_office")
  private Office office;
  //more fields
}

@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "S_OFFICE")
@Entity
public class Office extends {
  private Long idOffice
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_chamber")
  private Chamber chamber
  //more fields
}

@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "S_CHAMBER")
@Entity
public class Chamber{
  private Long id_chamber
  private String description;;
  //more fields
}
```

I am also using Spring Data Specifications to perform searches with filters.
The problem I have is when trying to get all the "Expedients" that were assigned at least once to a "Chamber", since I would have to look for those who have in the collection "assignments" at least one "Office" that belongs to a "Chamber."

---

I edit by adding more code. Keep in mind that the original code has several levels of inheritance (here simplified) and also the original model is in Spanish:

```
public class ExpedientSpecification implements Specification<Expedient> {
    private final Integer STATUS_DELETED = -1;
    protected ExpedientFilter criteria;
    protected List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    public ExpedientSpecification(ExpedientFilter criteria) {
        this.criteria=criteria;
    }

    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Expedient> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        //variable filters
        if(criteria.getId() != null){
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), criteria.getId())); 
        }
        if(criteria.getNumberExpedient() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("numberExpedient"), criteria.getNumberExpedient()));  
        }
        if(criteria.getYearExpedient() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("yearExpedient"), criteria.getYearExpedient()));  
        }
        //Fixed Filters
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get("status"), STATUS_DELETED));

        // This is where I need to add the filter. I need to get only those in the "assignments" List have at least one 
        // "Office" that belongs to a "Chamber"

        Predicate returnPredicates = cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[this.predicates.size()]));
        predicates.clear();
        return returnPredicates;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the solution can be using root.joinList. I keep investigating ...

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the criteria? Can you post the code?

Anyway you can join oneToMany normally with a criteria alias.

Example: `criteria.createAlias("assignments","assignments");` and then add a restriction on the atributte from assignments that you wish to filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it's not what I was needing. I added more code to be more specific. (Keep in mind that the original code has several levels of inheritance and also the original model is in Spanish)